# Trouble with getting an xml file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

When I'm viewing the source code of this page http://feeds.feedburner.com/Koreus-articles , it shows the source code as expected, a clean xml file

However when I'm trying with this :

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents('http://feeds.feedburner.com/Koreus-articles');
    echo $content;
?>
```

I'm getting this horrible thing : http://pastebin.com/s263M6sC i just don't get what just happened.

file_get_contents() works fine with any other simple page such as www.example.com, just not that xml file.

Any help appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `file_get_contents()` call to a `simplexml_load_file()` and then you can output the entire object with `print_r`:

```
$content = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.feedburner.com/Koreus-articles');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($content);
echo "</pre>";
```